# Simple collision detection for 2D match 3 gems game

Tags: 2d, collision-detection

I'm building simple match 3 game.
I have the parts where I move the gems with the mouse only in the straight X or straight Y, up and down and both sides, no 45 degrees movements on grid.
I'm looking for simple collision detection algorithm for the situation when for example:

a gem is moved up or down or left or right and there is another gem.
How can it detect it touched a gem and which gem it is?

Comment: It sounds more like you are looking for an algorithm to detect a valid move rather than collision.

Comment: You don't even need collision detection per se. Since your gems are arranged in a grid, just check the grid location where you want to move to and see if it's occupied.

Comment: Thanks , any idea on how to make it generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have all your gems contain their position (you probably do) and attach a method to the setter of that position so that it checks its surroundings for the gems around it.

In C# it would probably look something like this

```
private Vector2 mPos = something; // position of the gem
public Vector2 Position {
  get { return mPos; }
  set { mPos = value; GemMoved(mPos); }
}

public void GemMoved(Vector2 pPos) 
{
   var sameneighbours = map.FindNeighbours(this.Position, this.Color);
   ...
}
```

Another approach would simply to be check the board through for connected areas once a move is made. It's quite fast to check connected areas every time something happens unless your map is massive. By doing something like

```
bool[,] boardMarked = new bool[width, height];
boardMarked.Fill(false);
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
  for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    if(!boardMarked[x,y]) {
      int count = FindAndMarkConnected(x,y);
      if(count >= 3) EliminateAreAndGivePoints(x,y);
    }
  }
```